# Spring web application healthchecks

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I'm deploying Spring based web applications on Amazon's Beanstalk platform, and they give me the option of setting a "healthcheck" URL path for my application.

The idea is that their platform will do a request against that URL, after the deployment, to see if the application is successfully started. So, if the request results in an HTTP 200, the application is probably fine. But if it results in an HTTP 500 or something else, the platform knows there's a problem with the application.

So, I wish I could develop some kind of servlet that would check if the Spring Application Context was successfully initialised, or not, to give an appropriate HTTP response code to the platform.

Has anybody attempted something like this? For similar purposes?

I'm wondering if Spring already provides some elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest using health checks functionality from [Metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.1/manual/healthchecks.html). You could set up a number of classes that extend [`HealthCheck`](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.1/apidocs/index.html?com/codahale/metrics/servlets/HealthCheckServlet.html) class and implement `check()` method. These health check implementations would be Spring managed beans themselves and could autowire Spring beans and validate them. Then configure [`HealthCheckServlet`](http://metrics.codahale.com/manual/servlets/#healthcheckservlet) to monitor application state. Also check [metrics-spring](https://github.com/ryantenney/metrics-spring) project. It will make Spring and Metrics integration simpler.

If you are using Java Spring configuration you might have a Metrics config like this that extends `MetricsConfigurerAdapter` from metrics-spring

```
@Configuration
@EnableMetrics
public class MetricsConfig extends MetricsConfigurerAdapter { }
```

And then `@Import(value = {MetricsConfig.class})` to your Spring config.

You also need and implementation of `ServletContextListener` to wire up `HealthCheckServlet` and Spring. This `HealthCheckContextListener` should be added to your `web.xml`

```
public class HealthCheckContextListener extends
    HealthCheckServlet.ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private WebApplicationContext context;

    public HealthCheckContextListener(WebApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public HealthCheckContextListener() {}

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        this.context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()); 
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute(HealthCheckServlet.HEALTH_CHECK_REGISTRY,
            context.getBean(HealthCheckRegistry.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected HealthCheckRegistry getHealthCheckRegistry() {
        return (HealthCheckRegistry) context.getBean(HealthCheckRegistry.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting, but WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext only works if Spring's ContextLoaderListener is in web.xml, right?

Comment: Yes, `ContextLoaderListener` should either be defined in `web.xml` or set as listener in a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` Spring interface if you are running in a Servlet 3.0 environment without `web.xml`

Comment: The link in "..that extend HealthCheck class and implement .." refers to HealthCheckServlet but should be http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.1/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/health/HealthCheck.html

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing you can do is this:

```
@Controller
class HealthCheckController {

    @ResponseStatus(OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = HEAD) {
    public void ping() {
    }
}
```

Extendable to also test particular beans, DataSources etc.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with this approach is that the controller will only be activated if the Application Context has been properly initialised, right? Of course the result would be some HTTP error code, but it would not come from my code. Instead it would probably come from Tomcat.

Comment: There's no problem. If the app context is not initialized then your app is not working, is it? In which case Tomcat would return 404, which is perfectly reasonable and easily caught by the monitor. If the app context is initialized, but the health check controller finds something fishy, you can also return a 4XX or 5XX code. And if all is well, the health check controller will return 200 or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider what constitutes a healthy app for you (e.g., servlet tier? JMS queues? FTP servers? etc.) and have your health check verify those services' availability. Obviously the health check is going to run frequently, so you don't want to initiate expensive operations over and over again.

[Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) is a new project that aims to simplify Spring development by favoring convention instead of configuration. They have implemented a "health check" feature that you can add to a project via an Actuator [add-in module](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/README.md).

Here's a reference to their Health Check [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/SimpleHealthIndicator.java) -- it uses a controller class to return "ok" and, if there is a data source, attempts to run a query to confirm that the database is accessible (something like "SELECT .. from dual" in Oracle syntax).

Comment: Good point. For my specific case, I like to think that my application is in a healthy state if Spring's application context has been properly initialised. Most of the errors that could happen in my application would cause the creation and initialisation of Spring beans to fail.

Comment: One thing that really upsets me in the Spring Framework, is the fact that if the creation of one single bean fails, the whole thing falls apart. I wish there were ways to implement more resilient application contexts...

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done in the spring boot framework. By adding below dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can check the service by hitting the below URL.

localhost:serverPort/actuator/health